# Update Metasploitable 2

Tags: linux

Estoy haciendo pruebas de parcheo de vulnerabilidades y queria probarlo en la máquina Metasploitable 2. Concretamente intento parchear la vulnerabilidad de Shellshock con lo que seria suficiente con updatear bash. Para hacerlo escribo el siguiente comando:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bash
```

Pero recibo la siguiente salida:

```
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner Translation-en_US
Hit http://archive.canonical.com xenial Release
Ign http://archive.canonical.com xenial/partner Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com xenial Release.gpg

Reading package lists... Error!
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package python3-cffi-backend-api-min
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-http-message-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-psr-log-implementation
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-seclib
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-sabre-http
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package php-math-biginteger
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-max
W: Ignoring Provides line with DepCompareOp for package pypy-cffi-backend-api-min
E: Wow, you exceeded the number of package names this APT is capable of.
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

¿Alguién sabría decirme si es posible solucionar este problema o es que esta máquina está diseñada especificamente para que no pueda ser actualizada o parcheada?

Gracias.

Comment: *¿updatear?* ¿Qué hay de malo en usar *actualizar*?

Comment: Absolutamente nada, pero gracias.